# How to add calculated Columns to GridView at Runtime

Tags: acumatica

I have three DACs, People(PeopleID, Name), Skills(SkillID, Name) and SkillValues(PeopleID, SkillID, Value). When I add a record to Skills, it should be shown as a column in a Grid on my Graph that shows the list of People. This is the Code I have right now, but it doesn't add any columns to the Grid. However, it runs when I open the page, so I'm optimistic that it is possible somehow.

```
 public class MyGraph: PXGraph<MyGraph>
 {
    public MyGraph()
    {
        AddSkillColumns(MasterView.Cache);
    }

    private void AddSkillColumns(PXCache sender)
    {
        PXResultset<Skills> rows = SelectFrom<Skills>.View.Select(this);
        foreach (Skills row in rows)
        {
            String key = String.Format("Comp_{0}",row.SkillID.ToString());
            if(!sender.Fields.Contains(key))
            {
                sender.Fields.Add(key);
                this.FieldSelecting.AddHandler("MasterView", key, (PXCache cache, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs args) =>
                {

                });
                this.FieldUpdating.AddHandler("MasterView", key, (PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs args) =>
                {

                });
            }
        }
    }

    public SelectFrom<People>.View.ReadOnly MasterView;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your columns to the grid in the customization editor, and show / hide them in a RowSelected event if necessary.

Update:

If you really want to add your columns runtime, you can do it in the aspx.cs file of your screen. There is a good example in `GL302010.aspx.cs`

Comment: I know that is the way to add columns, but I have a variable amount of columns so I can‘t just add them. However, I could add like 20 and limit the amount of Skills to 20 as well..

Comment: Yeah, I see why you need this, please take a look at my update.